# bootstrap navbar toggle button is not visible in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter Bootstrap for my website and it has a fixed navbar on top. When I am resizing window in my desktop browser, everything is fine. When I am opening the same site on mobile, I can see `navbar-brand` but not the toggle button. I'm posting screenshots for a better understanding (first one is desktop firefox and second one is android):

[image: this is desktop browser resized]
[image: and the mobile screenshot]
This is driving me crazy!!!

**The Code:**

```css
.navbar-floating {
  background: black;
  color: #5b5656;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-floating .navbar-brand {
  color: #810000;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-floating .navbar-brand:after {
  content: ' | ';
  color: #810000;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
#floating-nav {
  position: fixed;
  /* display: none; */
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
#floating-nav.navbar {
  min-height: 1px;
}
#floating-nav ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
}
#floating-nav ul li a:hover {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-floating navbar-default" role="navigation" id="floating-nav" >
  <div class="container"> 
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hidden-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand scroll-top" href="#">DSA Media Group</a> </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hidden-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="slides">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="about">Agency</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="capabilities">Capabilities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="clients">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  </div>
  <!-- /.container --> 
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It works for me on my android smartphone (chrome & firefox)..

Comment: really? that's good news i guess! but why can't I see it then?

Comment: well cross-browser wise your code seems not to be optimized, in firefox does the navigation fold down on click, but not in in chrome.. but the button is shown in both.. I would recommend to remove all your custom CSS that concerns the navbar and just leave the bootstrap becuase this should work. Then test it on all devices/browsers and then add your custom CSS step by step while continuously testing until you find your troublemaker..

Comment: I'm trying that now.... :/

Comment: It is slow but it does appear (Chrome for android/ Nexus 5)

Comment: I feel like you are using resize function to re-render the navbar? FYI You should turn of pinch to zoom for mobile devices, it is screwing up your site.

Comment: @SamiaRuponti did you get an answer? I'm also using scroll spy. Would that be a problem?

Answer (score 8):

Just add a **navbar-default** class to the div wrapping your `<ul>` element like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-default" id="hidden-nav">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      ....
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and this didn't work for me.  Did this solution work for anyone else?

Comment: @JeremyMoritz Can you please provide a link to your website

Comment: I would like to, but the website isn't public.  It's an Android app I'm trying to build with Cordova.  It works fine online and on Android 5 devices, but the button is missing in Android 4.  Here's the HTML: http://pastebin.com/Q7mV3Sdx  (NOTE: The button shows up when i REMOVE the navbar-toggle class, but then it doesn't open up the navbar.)  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @JeremyMoritz Try adding navbar-default to this class instead--> `class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.navbar-dark` as

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-floating navbar-default" role="navigation" id="floating-nav" >
  <div class="container">
    .........
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution is really annoying

change `navbar-expand-sm` to `navbar-expand-lg` in side `<nav class=`

Answer (score 0):

It's inside of your bootstrap css. It's defined by default to hidde on md. all you gotta do is creat a new line in your style page.`.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler{display: block !important;}`